# The problem about expose prometheus web UI through nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have no idea what's the problem for my case.
I deploy an Prometheus server on AKS(Azure's k8s) and want to expose the Prometheus web UI through ingress controller for the following config.

And I also refer this

https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/user-guides/exposing-prometheus-and-alertmanager.html

```
# Prometheus
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  version: v2.13.1
  replicas: 2
  retention: 1d
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  ...
```

```
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus-service
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app: prometheus
```

```
# Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
# Just try another subpath make sure the nginx is work
#      - backend:
#          serviceName: aks-helloworld-one
#          servicePort: 80
#        path: /hello-world-one
      - backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /prometheus
```

I have added another path in my test stage, the nginx work successfully for aks-helloworld-one.
However, it not work for Prometheus server, I always got "404 page not found" in return.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it available when you `curl` your `prometheus-service` from another pod in the cluster ?

Comment: Yes, I also could expose prometheus through LoadBalnacer directly, however, in nginx way, it alwats have some problem

Comment: Any progress ? How do you access your `prometheus-service` directly ? Is it exposed on `/` or you need to add some additional path like `/prometheus` ? If it's available under `/`, you don't need any rewrites in your ingress and it should work straight away.

Comment: Hi, I think it is not a good choice to use  / directly. Actually, I want to expose prometheus server & thanos in their own sub path. ex. http://<server>/prometheus,  http://<server>/thanos.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know where the problem is. Actually my previous comment was wrong:

> If it's available under /, you don't need any rewrites in your ingress
> and it should work straight away.

Well... actually it won't for one simple reason. When you try to access your Prometheus UI via ingress, you use `<ingress ip>/prometheus` URL. Choosing `/prometheus` path redirects you correctly to the appropriate backend `Service`:

```
      - backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /prometheus
```

But the problem occurs because the `/prometheus` path (that you need to be redirected to the `prometheus-service` and eventually to one of the `Pods`, exposed by this `Service`) gets forwarded to the target `Pod` serving the actual content.

You get `404 page not found` error message because the http request that gets to the target webserver is claiming for the content of `/prometheus` directory instead of `/` from which it is actually served.

So if you change your ingress to something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

most probably everything would work as expected and you'll get the **Prometheus UI** website rather than `404 Not found`.

Well, although it may work, it's good only for debugging purposes as no one wants to use **ingress** just to be able to expose something under root path.

The following **ingress definition** should resolve your problem (Yes, **rewrites** are necessary in this scenario!):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
```

**Rewrite** that was used above will ensure that the original access path `/prometheus` gets rewritten to `/` before reaching the target `Pod`.

Comment: tks for your reply, however, it is still not work in my environment =(.
i decide to use root path temporilry.

Comment: So if you use a root `"/"` path for testing it works correctly, right ? And when you apply the rewrites it doesn't ?

Answer (score 1):

I am deploying the cluster in a AWS, I did this configuration with Helm Charts and it worked for me.

Ingress: Notice `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` and `path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)` in this file as mentioned in other answers.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "12h"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/acme-challenge-type: "http01"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myhost.cl
    secretName: mysecret-tls
  rules:
  - host: myhost.cl
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: monitoring-kube-prometheus-prometheus
            port:
              number: 9090
```

Prometheus: There is a label inside `spec` called `externalUrl` that makes you redirect whatever you want when you access in browser.

```
# Source: kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/prometheus.yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: monitoring-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: monitoring
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "19.0.2"
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus-stack
    chart: kube-prometheus-stack-19.0.2
    release: "monitoring"
    heritage: "Helm"
    prometheus: devops
spec:
  # ... Your data here
  externalUrl: http://myhost.cl/prometheus
```

Also be careful to not expose your prometheus instance and at least use an authentication method like basic auth, here's something that can help you with that: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is with your rewrite-target & path, can you try with a sub-domain, rather than path to confirm? I have the following Prometheus Ingress working on Subdomain

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-ingress
  name: prometheus-monitoring
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: prometheus
    servicePort: 9090   #As my service is listening on 9090
  rules:
  - host: prometheus-monitoring.DOMAIN
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: prometheus
          servicePort: 9090   #As my service is listening on 9090
        path: /
```

And below is my service manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: prometheus
    chart: prometheus-operator-5.11.0
    heritage: Tiller
  name: prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 9090
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app: prometheus
    prometheus: k8s
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: I have tried it but still not work, could I have your Service config? tks ~

Comment: Added in the answer